# Transform URL appearance and send it by Telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using a Telegram Bot to send informations from python script.

My function to send message to my Telegram Bot is :

```
def telegram_bot_sendtext(bot_message):

    bot_token = 'token'
    bot_chatID = 'id'
    send_text = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&parse_mode=Markdown&text=' + bot_message
    response = requests.get(send_text)

    return response.json()
```

One of the informations is a variable called "URL", which contains URL, for example, this one : https://www.sezane.com/fr/product/collection-printemps-all-0804/robe-will?cou_Id=859

I have two questions :

1. When I'm using other variables, everything OK. However, sending URL variable, nothing happens and I don't receive any message
2. How can I do to receive the link as "link with short name" and not as entire link ? For example, receive "Google" instead of "www.google.com" ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: about which point ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) The `markdown` parseMode requires a valid markdown syntax, I guess the `_` in your example url starts a [Markdown italic text](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdown-style) which is never closed, Telegram returns a error and the message will not be send. Use [`parse_mode: HTML`](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#html-style) to disable this. (There are no `_` elements in html parsemode)

2) Both `markDown` and `HTML` parsemode provide options to add a hyperlink to the message;

**HTML**

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

**MarkDown**

```
[Google](https://www.google.com/)
```

```py
telegram_bot_sendtext("Please press this [link](https://www.sezane.com/fr/product/collection-printemps-all-0804/robe-will?cou_Id=859)")
```

For more information, please take a look at there [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how to use it in my request

Comment: @AlexDana Use the MarkDown syntax as regular text when calling your function. I added an example to the answer

Comment: thanks very much. One last small question : when using a variable indlink = string URL, the link is not clikable. any idea ?  telegram_bot_sendtext("Please press this [link](indlink)")